# glCreateProgram Access violation executing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, opengl, access-violation

I have initialized GLFW and i can call other gl functions. It is possible to draw faces using the OpenGL pipeline. It, however gives me this error when executing `glCreateProgram()`.

Error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in Voxel.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation executing location 0x00000000.

Simplified code:

```
void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    cerr << description << endl;
}
[...]
if (!glfwInit())
    {
        cout << "Failed to create GLFW3 / OpenGL context";
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        cout << "GLFW3 initialized!" << endl;

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
width = 600;
    height = 600;
    this->window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "voxel", NULL, NULL);
    glfwSetWindowSize(this->window, width, height);
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    if (!this->window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(this->window);
    glfwSwapInterval(0);

    cout << "OpenGL version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;
GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
[...]
```

I do not see, why this is happening.

Comment: Looks like your program is calling a function using a pointer, but the pointer is NULL.

Comment: Shouldnt be the case, since glfw should initialize everything!

Comment: `error_callback` is a function?

Comment: yes. I'll just add that to the code. This one shouldnt make problems though.

Comment: @Addi: GLFW will **not** act as an extension loader for OpenGL. Calling any OpenGL function above GL 1.1 requires you to use the GL extension mechanism, if you want your program to be portable (depending on the platform and GL implementation, there might be different guarantees).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLFW doesn't load extensions and modern functionality for you. Hence glCreateProgram is uninitialized.

You need an actual extension loader. Also you have to check that glCreateProgram et al. are actually supported by your target system.